# Initialize Array of Custom Types in Structured Text Syntax

Tags: plc, st, codesys

In my project I have a type like:

```
TYPE myDataStruct :
STRUCT
    A : UINT;
    B : WORD;
    C : REAL;
    D : Custom_Obj;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE
```

And I need to keep an array of this type for persistent memory. I can't just use `VAR RETAIN` because this particular piece of memory needs to persist through a download. The controller I am using has a way to do this but in order for it to work I need to be able to set the array equal to an initial value. So if I have declared

```
myarray := ARRAY[0..20] OF myDataStruct;
```

How do I then initialize this array to a blank array? What is the equivalent of `new` in other languages?

I have guessed

```
myarray := [21(A := 0,
               B := '',
               C := 0.0,
               D := ??? )];
```

But that doesn't appear to be right. It could be simplified if there were only one level deep of custom structs and for this application I could do that. However, I still don't think I have the syntax right.

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the equivalent of `new` in other languages?

The analog of this is

```
VAR
    EmptyArray  : ARRAY[0..20] OF myDataStruct;
END_VAR
```

If you want to pre-populate it with default values

```
VAR
    EmptyArray  : ARRAY[0..20] OF myDataStruct := [
        (A := 100, B := 200, С := 0.0, D := ???),
        (A := 34, B := 45, С := 0.1, D := ???),
        ..... etc
    ];
END_VAR
```

For CoDeSys 2.3 delete `[` and `]`.

What you have to understand that `EmptyArray` is not a prototype of data you need but already initialized variable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to initialize it in `"x = new struct()"` way. You also can't assign the whole array in the code with something like `myarray = [1, 2, 3] etc`, as far as I know.

If you just want to set it empty with values like 0, '', etc, then there are two ways that I would use:

**1. Use `MEMSET` function to set all bytes to 0**

[Link to the online help](https://help.codesys.com/webapp/m0ZSKwt2k9t9COsbw6YPd_jvtjs%2FMemSet;product=MemoryUtils;version=3.5.9.0)

```
//Something like
MemSet(
    pbyBuffer   := ADR(myarray),    //Address of the variable
    byValue     := 0,               //Byte that address is filled with
    dwSize      := SIZEOF(myarray)  //How many bytes? (variable size)
)
```

**2. Create a dummy variable and assign it to the `myarray`**

The variable is always initialized to zeros, so EmptyArray values are all 0/empty etc.

```
VAR
    EmptyArray  : ARRAY[0..20] OF myDataStruct;
END_VAR

//In the code
myarray := EmptyArray;
```

I hope I understood your question correctly.